# Idiomatic way to read two lines at a time from stdin

Tags: perl

I am not much of a Perl user, so I am not that comfortable with all the many and varied Perl idioms out there.

Is there an idiomatic way to read two lines at a time from stdin into an array?

Comment: If you are looking for something like `while (<>)` that reads two lines at the time, I think the answer is no. But you can always hack something together like `while ($first = <>) { $second = <>; ` but then you have to be sure that you are not reading past the end of the file.

Comment: @TLP I'm interested in what an experienced Perl user would consider idiomatic and good style.

Comment: You're in luck then, as I am an experienced Perl user, and I gave you my answer about a lack of an idiomatic solution, but gave you an option that might work.

Comment: What Tlp wrote `while ($first = <>) { $second = <> // last;` this is with check included, and ignoring last line if they are odd in total.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to iterate, and on each each iteration the array contains just the latest two lines (i.e. lines1&2, then lines 3&4, etc) Or does the array grow over time, in steps of two lines? Or do you want to just read the first two lines from a file and then stop?

Comment: @TLP then your experienced Perl user's response would serve better as an answer that can I can accept and will appear in search results for future users, rather than a dismissive comment that benefits nobody.

Comment: @shadowtalker I felt that the comment was informative, that was why I made it. Would you have preferred that no one said anything and your question just got closed?

Comment: shadowtalker-- This isn't much of a question to answer, since reading input is in general a line-oriented business (so to say), so there'd be no idioms for doing something other. So @TLP first comment did justice to it, I thought. I didn't notice that it was dismissive (?).  Their second comment was a response to your (arguably disrespectful) inquiry about an "experienced" user (right after they gave you an answer!), so that's just off-topic so please don't complain.  So I'd say: leave it now, you got an answer; nice of you to offer to accept it and watch if more comes.  I am voting to close.

Comment: (To clarify, just in case: I don't mean to dog your question -- on the contrary, I appreciate inquiries about idiomatic ways to do things! It's just that the quest is opposite to common and there wouldn't be idioms for it, and so the "answer" is: "no". My opinions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not an idiomatic way to get two lines of input in one go. But, you can write your own. Your subroutine can do whatever you need to do (such as skip blank lines or comment lines):

```
my @two_lines = get_two_lines( $filehandle );
```

But, it's your task that really controls what you are doing. Maybe it makes more sense for that to be something like this:

```
while( my $first_line = <> ) {
    my $second_line = <>; # read again
    if( ! defined $second_line ) { ... }
    ...
    }
```

Don't become infatuated with idioms though. Some things that an experienced person would do look cryptic to other people. Not only that, experienced people disagree on the appropriateness of some idioms.

If you are writing code that experienced people will read, just ask them what they prefer. Write it in the way that you know how, and eventually someone will complain. A better question might be "Is this a good way to do this?", then show us what you are doing.